# Querying discriminated collection by ID using Doctrine MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

How can I query for an object knowing only its ObjectId using Doctrine MongoDB? Queries by id, using `$dm->findOneBy(array('id' => $id))` will only return a result for one of the discriminated document types, but not others. Querying via the command line, e.g. `db.documents.find({ "_id": ObjectId(...) });` returns the expected row.

**Edit:** The issue appears to be that, if I don't know the type of document I'm querying for and I'm using a custom repository, the document name that is used is tied to the class name of only one of the two document classes (hence returning 0 results for other types of documents). This generally makes sense, because if I don't know what type of document I'm looking for how should Doctrine? Given a discriminated collection, is there any way to automagically use the right document name in the repository without explicitly telling doctrine?

See below for an abstraction of the problem.

Thanks!

---

I have a set of discriminated documents living in the same *documents* collection, discriminated by their `type` field e.g.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("510fdb6c91a4cb4c25000000"),
  "name" : "Contract",
  "type" : "document"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("510fdb6c91a4cb4c25000001"),
  "name" : "Tutorial",
  "length_min": "60"
  "type" : "video"
}
...
```

My mapping for both `Document` and `Video` classes looks like:

```
<!-- "Doc" Document mapping -->
<doctrine-mongo-mapping ...>
  <document name="Doc" collection="documents" repository-class="DocRepository">
    <discriminator-field fieldName="type" />
    <discriminator-map>
      <discriminator-mapping value="document" class="Doc" />
      <discriminator-mapping value="video" class="Video" />
    </discriminator-map>

    <field fieldName="id" id="true" />
    <field fieldName="name" field="name" type="string" />
  </document>
</doctrine-mongo-mapping>

<!-- "Video" Document mapping -->
<doctrine-mongo-mapping ...>
  <document name="Video" collection="documents" repository-class="DocRepository">
    <discriminator-field fieldName="type" />
    <discriminator-map>
      <discriminator-mapping value="document" class="Doc" />
      <discriminator-mapping value="video" class="Video" />
    </discriminator-map>

    <field fieldName="id" id="true" />
    <field fieldName="name" field="name" type="string" />
    <field fieldName="length_min" field="length_min" type="int" />
  </document>
</doctrine-mongo-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I see only one solution, without resorting to creating some additional wrapper repositories like Sean Quinn above suggested.

I'd use a single collection for all the documents that are discriminated - if you don't have a base class for all of the classes you are storing, I'd add some abstract class. It is described in [Doctrine documentation about inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). Long story short, you use only one collection, some field informs about the class of a stored object, and after querying this repository you get an object of a proper class.

To use single collection inheritance mapping, you add `inheritance-type="SINGLE_COLLECTION"` attribute to a top-class `document` tag.

Comment: Yeah, I came to pretty much the same conclusion after looking at it for a while; originally I was looking at using the `mapped-superclass` construct but they can't have custom repositories associated with them as far as I can tell. Thanks for the suggestion of the `SINGLE_COLLECTION` inheritance type.

Answer (score 1):

The two solutions I came up with for this problem were:

1. To create different repositories that were merely wrappers around the actual abstracted repository doing the work. This creates an overhead of dependency injection.
2. To acquire the shared repository with a class name qualifier so that I am querying for the proper types of objects.

Both solutions still require knowing the class name (or at least its type so that the appropriate class can be derived).